# Again about max-height: N% in CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I know that if we specify `max-height` property in percentages it's calculated relatively to the parent container `height` property. But for some reason I've got it working with unknown parent `height` in Chrome and Opera, and it doesn't work in IE and Firefox.

My styles (simplified):

```
div.boxForSlide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
// I use this to center slide vertically, cause boxForSlide height is in percentages
div.boxForSlide:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 90%;
}
div.slide div.image-body {
  float: right;
  width: 35%;
}
div.slide div.image-body img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 80%;
}
```

My html (simplified):

```
<div class="boxForSlide">
  <div class="slide" >
    <div class="content">
      <!-- some html -->
      <div class="slide-body">
        <!-- some html that is floated as div.image-body -->
        <div class="image-body">
          <img src="bla bla">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In short I have a slide (div) that I center vertically with `max-height: 90%`. Then inside `slide-body` I have a header and a bunch of div's that are floated (including `div.image-body`). Then when I decrease the browser height I want the image height to decrease as well (to be `max-height: 80%` of the slide). And I get it working properly in Chrome and Opera. But it doesn't work in Firefox and IE.

**My questions:**
**1)** Why does it work anyway?? (the parent height is unknown)
**2)** Why doesn't it work in Firefox and IE??

**Edits (1):**
Tested in all latest browser versions.

**Edits (2):**
Here is a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yycaX/1/
Hristo Valkanov, thx for creating it :)

I'm testing it in:
Opera (version 22.0.1471.700) - works
Chrome (version 35.0.1916.153 m) - works
Firefox (version 30.0) - doesn't work
IE (version 11.0.10) - doesn't work

Comment: tested in Chrome and FF, Ubuntu 14.04. No difference between the 2. Works perfectly. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yycaX/1/)

Comment: thx Hristo, I have 30.0 Firefox version. What version have you tested in?

Comment: 30.0 Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0. Currently I don't have a PC with Windows nearby to test it on IE 11

Comment: hm, I'm testing on widnows..